# Merging Multiple KML Files

Tags: python, xml, bash, merge, kml

I cannot find a script to easily merge kml files; any ideas?

Ideally I'd like something along the lines of `kmlmerge $file $file`, as I'm already working on a shell script for managing multiple kismet drone nodes.

Comment: Merge in what way?  Do the two source files duplicate some of the information?  Are there possible conflicts?  Or are you simply trying to automate the effect of stripping the root element off the second file and basically appending its entire contents to the contents of the first file's root element (which you can do with a text editor in about 15 seconds)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is xml-cat of the xml-coreutils package (or xmlstarlet) to merge XML files.

see: [Extracting Nodes from multiple xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159104/extracting-nodes-from-multiple-xml-files)